# How can I perform HTTP request caching in a node.js CLI application that persists once the application has exited?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a node.js CLI application that uses the GitHub API. Instead of making several HTTP requests to the GitHub every time the app is invoked, I'd like to cache responses and use the `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers to determine if I need to make a request.

How can I persist these requests on a user's machine without resorting to reading from and writing to flat files in the user's home directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting it to persist when the app isn't running, then storing to a file is your simplest option. You could do it with a redis cache or local sql database, but then your user has to set *that* up too.

You could use something like [`memory-cache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache) to have it cache the response *while* the app is running though, and just rely on a single new HTTP request each time the app starts up.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has a variable called `__dirname` which points to the directory the current running script resides in. If a package is installed via NPM, this corresponds to the global `node_modules` folder, which scripts have read/write access to. I ended up using the `trivialdb` package to store a JSON file in this directory.

One caveat: the folder will be overwritten if the user updates the package, so if you want to store data that persists through multiple installs of your package, storing in the user's home directory is probably the best bet.